# How to apply Serverless to an existing Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

When I try deploy to an existing lambda function configured in serverless.yml as following, it says "An error occurred: ApiLambdaFunction - an-existing-function-name-created-by-my-devops already exists."

```
functions:
  api:
    name: an-existing-function-name-created-by-my-devops
```

So it is not allowed to deploy to an existing lambda not created by serverless?

Comment: Our problem is we are using terraform to create the lambda, so we are not using cloud formation.  So I have the same question, can we use serverless to update an existing lambda, or is there another solution?  Let me know if you ever figured this out.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As Serverless manages your resources via a CloudFormation Stack, you could probably be able to import the lambda function within the UI ([Import Existing Resources into a CloudFormation Stack](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/)) and do the deploy afterwards again.

I did not try this and there's most probably a better solution though.

**Edit**: precondition is that you successfully created your stack before adding your desired function.